# How to save checked checkboxes in a CheckboxSelectMultiple field in an edit form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I made a form for a model, and now I want to create an update form for that model, but I'm having trouble with the CheckboxSelectMultiple field. Here is my code:

choices.py

```
FREQUENCY_CHOICES = (('sunday', 'Sunday'), ('monday', 'Monday'), ('tuesday', 'Tuesday'), ('wednesday', 'Wednesday'), ('thursday', 'Thursday'), ('friday', 'Friday'), ('saturday', 'Saturday'))
```

models.py

```
class Schedules(models.Model):
    course_name = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='south_plainfield')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=ROOM_CHOICES, default='A')
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.date.today)
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=START_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=END_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor)
    total_hours = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=TOTAL_HOURS_CHOICES, default='six')
    # Relevant code here
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, default='1 day')
    initiated_by = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    schedule_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

forms.py

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    course_name = CourseChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.filter(status=True), label="Course Name", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, initial='south_plainfield', label="Location", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    room = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROOM_CHOICES, initial='A', label="Room", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    start_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y'], label="Start Date", widget=DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'), help_text="MM/DD/YYYY")
    start_time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=START_TIME_CHOICES, initial='eight-thirty am', label="Start Time", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    interval = forms.ChoiceField(choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, initial='1 day', label="Interval", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    # hours_per_class = forms.ChoiceField(choices=HOURS_PER_CLASS_CHOICES, initial='four_and_half', label="Hours Per Class", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    total_hours = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TOTAL_HOURS_CHOICES, initial='six', label="Total Hours", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    instructor = InstructorChoiceField(queryset=Instructor.objects.all(), label="Instructor", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    end_time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=END_TIME_CHOICES, initial='eight-thirty am', label="End Time", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    # Relevant code here
    frequency = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=FREQUENCY_CHOICES, label="Frequency", help_text="Please select at least one")
    status = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, label="Status")

    class Meta:
        model = Schedules
        fields = ('course_name', 'instructor', 'location', 'room', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'interval', 'total_hours', 'frequency', 'status',)
```

views.py

```
def update_Schedule(request, pk):
    schedule = get_object_or_404(Schedules, pk=pk)
    form = ScheduleForm(request.POST or None, instance=schedule)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('schedule_list')
    return render(request, "schedule/update_schedule.html", {'form':form})
```

update_schedule.html

```
{% block main_content %}
<style>
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
</style>
<h2>Update Course Schedule</h2>
<br>
<form id="update_schedule_form" method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="col-gl-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>{{ field.errors }}</strong>
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                    <br>
                    {{ field }}
                    <script></script>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Schedule</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

For some reason, the choices that are checked in the frequency field do not stay checked when go to the update form for an instance, even though the rest of the fields do. I know that this is is the only field that accepts multiple choices. Curiously, the table I made returns the frequency as an array. I know this has been asked before, but that did not get an answer, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this dilemma. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Apparently I was supposed to change the field in the model to MultiSelectField.